# Intellij Plugin to scan code security (locally)

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

any recommendation to install and run locally any plugin on Intellij to avoid security vulnerabilities like SQL Injections, it is not an open source project, written in Java.

Thanks a lot

Comment: what about Sonar Lint plugin, did you try it ?

Comment: OWASP Dependency Check checks if the versions of the dependencies have public vulnerabilities.

Comment: But not sql injections

Comment: @AndreiLisa I tried, and not sql injections are detected

Comment: [14538-reshift-security](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14538-reshift-security)

Comment: @AndreiLisa Thanks, I just run reshift and sql injections are not detected :(